# Angular BehaviorSubject not updating mat table UI after mat sort

Tags: angular, mat-table, behaviorsubject

I have a mat-table that I wanted to add sorting to. I added the `MatSort` and `mat-sort-header` tags to my table/headers and also added the `(MatSortChange)` event to the table. I have a behavior subject that acts as my dataSource, and in `ngOnInit` I get the initial data from the backend. From there, if a user wants to sort, they click the sort header, and it calls the change event which calls my custom function to sort my data. At the end of my sorting function I call `behaviorSubject.next(sortedData)` and my table UI doesn't update. I have checked the value right before the `.next()` call and it is correct. I have also logged `behaviorSubject.value` and that is also showing the correct data, but the table UI doesn't update.

Table HTML

```
<div *ngIf="(this.dataSource$ | async) as dataSource">
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.id}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}} </td>
   </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
dataSource$: BehaviorSubject<Person[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
...

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.service.getData().subscribe((val) => this.dataSource$.next(val));

sortData(event: MatSort) {
   const columnToSort = event.active;
   const direction = event.direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
   const data = this.dataSource$.value;
   data.sort((a, b) => {
     if(a[columnToSort] < b[columnToSort]) {
       return -1 * direction;
     } else {
       return 1 * direction;
     }
   });
   this.dataSource$.next(data);
}
```

Comment: Did you check by clicking multiple times if it is resetting the direction? May be direction is setting to ''. You can check matSortDisableClear attribute on matSort element. - To prevent the user from clearing the sort state from an already sorted column, set matSortDisableClear to true on the matSort to affect all headers, or set disableClear to true on a specific header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference never changes, the mat table requires that to know to rerender. You can use the spread operator to make a copy of your data:

```
sortData(event: MatSort) {
  //... 
  this.dataSource$.next([...data]);
}
```